# Exporting popcorn.js project to mp4

Tags: xml, json, popcornjs

I'm about to start a new project with Mozilla's Popcorn tools and I was wondering if there is a way to export the final results to an mp4-file.

My idea is to export the full timeline with events to XML and then send it to an encoder. Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is it easy to export all the events to XML (or maybe JSON).
2. Are there any encoding tools (available for *nix-systems/Amazon S3), that use XML (or JSON) and can merge video, audio, pictures and text?